# Why am I getting the following compiler errors with the SoundCloud API?

Tags: iphone, xcode, soundcloud

I have created an iPhone application. I want to integrate SoundCloud API with my application. I have created one separate application to integrate SoundCloud API. It is working fine with SoundCloud API.

But I tried to integrate with my existing application, I am getting following error. Already I have added the SoundCloud API code to my existing application.

error:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Alex/project/../../iHearFmod/iphoneos3.1.3/System/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCSoundCloudAPIConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-SCSoundCloudAPIConfiguration in MyProjectAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCSoundCloudAPI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-SCSoundCloudAPI in MyProjectAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find on soundclound doc:

> The Mac framework should be copied into your application and linked to your target. Also add a build phase to your target that copies the framework to the Frameworks destination.

Did you do the last step ?